# parameter is not valid for image.fromstream()

Tags: vb.net, stream

Dim strsql As String
get data from access database in vb.net

```
    Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim img As Image

        strsql = " select HotelName,HotelAddress,HotelPhoneNum,HotelPicture,HotelDesc from Hotel_3Star where ID = " & intIndex & ";"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, connection)
        Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader
        myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        myreader.Read()

        Dim nameHotel As String = myreader("HotelName")
        Dim phoneNumHotel As String = myreader("HotelPhoneNum")
        Dim descHotel As String = myreader("HotelDesc")

        Dim PictHotel = myreader("HotelPicture")
        stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(PictHotel, Byte()))
```

it says that the parameter is not valid

```
        img = Image.FromStream(stream) 'here the error detected

        lblHotelName.Text = nameHotel
        lblPhoneNum.Text = phoneNumHotel
        lblHotelDesc.Text = descHotel

        pcbHotel.Image = img

        connection.Close()
```

Comment: Specify the Data Type of `HotelPicture` and show how the Image was stored.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119798/loading-picture-stored-in-access-database-into-program-vb-net